# Create AngularJS Ng Elements From Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would just like to know how to create this **from javascript using angularJS**:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="TheText">{{TheText}}
```

For example using something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div id="Holder"></div>

        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('myCtrl', function() {
                var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" ng-model="TheText">{{TheText}}';
                document.getElementById("Holder").appendChild(newdiv);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I assume you would have to use $compile or something like that but I don't seem to get any of that working. Basically the problem is that any ng directives dont't see to work when I create it this way.

**SOLUTION:**

Use custom directives, this answer solves my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div mydiv></div>

        <script>
            angular.module("myApp", [])
            .directive("mydiv", function() {
                return {
                    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="TheText">{{TheText}}'
                };
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to try simple (but powerful) html() method:

```
iElement.html('<svg width="600" height="100" class="svg"></svg>');
```

Or append as an alternative:

```
iElement.append('<svg width="600" height="100" class="svg"></svg>');
```

And , of course , more cleaner way:

```
 var elt = angular.element('<input type="text" ng-model="TheText">{{TheText}}');
 iElement.append(elt);
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, would you might explaining the answer a bit more please? I don't understand where iElement comes from